# Создание приложения для сохранений закладок на C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, мне захотелось написать приложение для сохранения закладок, так как часто натыкаюсь в интернете на статьи или какую-то информацию, которая интересна или могла понадобиться бы мне в дальнейшем, сохраняю ссылки куда-нибудь в личные сообщения, а потом забываю о них. Поэтому захотелось иметь приложение, где можно всё структурировать, разделить по группам и т.д.
Так как изучаю C#, то хочу использовать его.
Работу этого приложения я представляю таким образом:
1.На интересующей странице в браузере нажимаем правой кнопкой мышки и выбираем сохранить в *название приложения* (возможно сразу здесь сделать выбор группы, в которой ссылка будет храниться в приложении, и ввести краткое описание, что собственно тут такое).
2.Через меню приложения выбираем интересующую нас закладку и ссылка открывается в определённом браузере.

Теперь нубский вопрос: возможно такое реализовать на C#  и в какую сторону мне копать (что нужно) именно для связи приложения на C# с браузером?

Comment: Вам нужно написать расширение для браузера. В каждом браузере это делается по-своему. Поэтому определитесь с конкретным браузером и гуглите, как именно это делается для него. О C# придётся забыть (только если речь не об IE - для него можно с помощью COM заюзать C#).

Comment: а почему не разобраться с имеющимся функционалом закладок? выбор конечно за вами, но все популярные браузеры позволяют создавать папки в закладках и размещать туда интересующие ссылки в пару кликов.

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу смысла писать свою программу, если есть возможность сохранять и структурировать закладки напрямую в ЛЮБОМ браузере.

1. Идете в Bookmarks Manager и создаете нужную структуру категорий
2. Ставите на браузер Xmarks и таким макаром уберегаешь себя от того что закладки потеряются т.к. ты забыл забекапить их. Он будет заливать их на сервер автоматически при каждом закрытии браузера, а так же сохранять историю изменений закладок.
3. ...
4. profit!